# Filling polygon with strokes in OpenLayers 3

Tags: polygon, openlayers, visualisation, fill

I want to create a polygon and have it filled with strokes as in the image:

[image]

Currently, my style function looks like this:

```py
var tempObjectsStyleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
return [
    new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: feature.get('color')
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: feature.get('color'),
            width: 5
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 20,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: feature.get('color')
            })
        })
    })
];
```

};

What do I need to modify in order to support strokes in the fill?

Comment: Try https://rawgit.com/ca0v/ol3-lab/v3.20.1/rawgit.html?run=ol3-lab/labs/style-viewer&geom=point&style=%5B%7B%22circle%22:%7B%22fill%22:%7B%22pattern%22:%7B%22orientation%22:%22horizontal%22,%22color%22:%22rgba(10,20,134,1)%22,%22spacing%22:5,%22repitition%22:%22repeat%22%7D%7D,%22opacity%22:1,%22stroke%22:%7B%22color%22:%22rgba(0,255,0,1)%22,%22width%22:1%7D,%22radius%22:64%7D%7D,%7B%22image%22:%7B%22anchor%22:%5B16,48%5D,%22imgSize%22:%5B32,48%5D,%22anchorXUnits%22:%22pixels%22,%22anchorYUnits%22:%22pixels%22,%22src%22:%22http://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/data/icon.png%22%7D%7D%5D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an example on the OpenLayers examples website: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/canvas-gradient-pattern.html

Basically, you have to create a [`CanvasPattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasPattern) in a [HTMLCanvasElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement) to fill with an OpenLayers 3 [`ol.style.Fill`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.style.Fill.html) style. Check out the [issue](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/2208) for more info. Also, check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61b7szjn/) with an example that's a lot more like your image.

Answer (score 2):

The `ol.style.Fill` accepts a color property of the type of `CanvasRenderingContext2D.fillStyle`. This can be used to style your polygons with an image pattern (e.g. like in QGIS / ArcGIS).

Currently, I don't know a way to programmatically create these strokes so you need to provide an image with them.

After that, you can use the following code:

```js
  var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source
  });

  var cnv = document.createElement('canvas');
  var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/222/Canvas_createpattern.png'; // your image here
  img.onload = function() {
  var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');

    layer.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
       fill: new ol.style.Fill({
         color: pattern
       })
    }));
  }
```

See this example of a fully working version: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmarquar/toh7tw7h/14/)

Comment: Thank you , but how do I use different colors ? Each polygon has attribute if its blue , red , green etc....

Answer (score 1):

```
style: new ol.style.Style({
          fill: new ol.style.FillPattern(
            {
                pattern: "hatch",
                ratio: 1,
                color: 'yellow',
                offset: 0,
                scale: 2,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)" }),
                size: 2,
                spacing: 10,
                angle: 0
            })
            
        })
```